# C# Event fires a lot of times

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I am using a CollectionView that receives data in a custom ViewModel from my webpage as long as it returns a JSON with the data. Once the `Offset` in the call >= `num_of_rows` the webpage prints `"Nothing"`. If that happens I set a boolean `HitBottomOfList = true;`. Now everytime when it wants to do a webcall it checks if the `HitBottomOfList == false`.

### Full Code

ViewModel:

```
public class TemplateListViewModel
{
    public double WidthHeight { get; set; }

    public ICommand LoadTemplates => new Command(LoadTemplateList);
    public int CurrentTemplateCountReceived;
    public bool HitBottomOfList = false;
    public ObservableCollection<TemplateSource> sourceList { get; set; }


    public TemplateListViewModel()
    {
        CurrentTemplateCountReceived = 0;
        sourceList = new ObservableCollection<TemplateSource>();

        var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
        var width = mainDisplayInfo.Width;
        var density = mainDisplayInfo.Density;
        var ScaledWidth = width / density;

        WidthHeight = (ScaledWidth / 2);

        loadingTemplates += onLoadingTemplates;
        LoadTemplateList();
    }

    private event EventHandler loadingTemplates = delegate { };

    private void LoadTemplateList()
    {
        loadingTemplates(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private async void onLoadingTemplates(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (HitBottomOfList == false)
        {
            List<Template> templateList = await App.RestService.GetTemplates(App.User, CurrentTemplateCountReceived);

            if (templateList != null)
            {
                foreach (var template in templateList)
                {
                    ImageSource source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("mysite.org/myapp/" + template.FileName));
                    TemplateSource templateSource = new TemplateSource { Id = template.Id, Source = source, WidthHeight = WidthHeight, FileName = template.FileName };
                    sourceList.Add(templateSource);
                }

                CurrentTemplateCountReceived = sourceList.Count;
            }
            else
            {
                HitBottomOfList = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding sourceList}" RemainingItemsThreshold="6"
RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding LoadTemplates}">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
    Span="2" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <ff:CachedImage
    Source="{Binding Source}"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    WidthRequest="{Binding WidthHeight}"
    HeightRequest="{Binding WidthHeight}">
                <ff:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="imgTemplate_Clicked" />
                </ff:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
            </ff:CachedImage>

        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

And finally the WebCall that I do:

```
public async Task<List<Template>> GetTemplates(User user, int offset)
{
    var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("un", user.Username));
    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("pw", user.Password));
    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("offset", offset.ToString()));
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
    var weburl = "mysite.org/myapp/get_templates.php";
    List<Template> response = await PostResponseTemplates(weburl, content);

    return response;
}

public async Task<List<Template>> PostResponseTemplates(string weburl, FormUrlEncodedContent content)
{
    var response = await client.PostAsync(weburl, content);
    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    if (json != "Nothing")
    {
        var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        var templatePropery = jObject["Templates"] as JArray;
        List<Template> templateList = new List<Template>();

        foreach (var property in templatePropery)
        {
            List<Template> propertyList = new List<Template>();
            propertyList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Template>>(property.ToString());
            templateList.AddRange(propertyList);
        }

        var sourcePropery = (JObject)jObject["Source"];
        foreach (var property in sourcePropery)
        {
            string tempplateSource = property.Value.Value<string>();
            App.TemplateSource = tempplateSource;
        }

        return templateList;
    }
    else
    {
        ErrorMessage = json;
        return default(List<Template>);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that when it does trigger the `RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding LoadTemplates}"`
it executes the command a lot of times after each other, thinking it needs more data, while there is already a command to get new data. This causes the app to get new data with the same `offset` a few times, so the app will the same data in the CollectionView a lot of times.

I want the app to call the webpage 1 time to receive more images and just let it load, without asking again for new data, so the duplicates in the list will disappear.
So how can I make sure it only asks the data once, when almost hit the bottom?

### Update

Using @Jason his code the following is going wrong:
When the code goes through the `MyHandler`, it fires the `LoadTemplateList();` But jumps to the `handling = false;` before it finished, so the next command is allowed to start, without finishing the other. Any idea how to wait for the method to finish?

Comment: What's the event for? Seems superfluent to me.

Comment: The CollectionView will trigger the event if it has almost hit the bottom of the CollectionView. It fires a method that collects more data, but that event gets fired many times, which causes the app do collect duplicate data

Comment: Actually, no. It triggers a command that executes a Method which in turn will call the event delegate which will trigger the event handler ... while you could just have the Command execute a Method. But I think that will not solve your problem. I just found that a _little_ bit convoluted.

Comment: Okay, but do you know how to fix it, because right now the `Command` gets executed many times, so blocking it in the `method` doesn't work, because I already tried that with the `HitBottomOfList` variable

Comment: Still in the process of understanding what is possibly happening here.

Comment: Do you want the `App.RestService.GetTemplates(App.User, CurrentTemplateCountReceived)` code as well? Thats the webcall that my app does in the event!

Comment: I don't think this is related to the problem.

Comment: I added it to the question, because maybe it can help you understand my code and problem, or **if** you want to recreate it

Comment: Just took a glance through, but it looks like `CurrentTemplateCountReceived = sourceList.Count;` is always being set the same number. Should it be `CurrentTemplateCountReceived += sourceList.Count;` so the CurrentTemplateCountReceived is actually incremented?

Comment: sourceList is global, so that should just add values to it, so the asking for count should be enough, instead of adding something to the count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a bool to track if you are already handling the event and ignore any new ones

```
bool handling = false;

public void MyHandler()
{
  // already handling an event, ignore the new one
  if (handling) return;

  handling = true;

  // process event here

  handling = false;
}
```

Comment: I still get the same result after this code. The code inside the `onLoadingTemplates` still get called a lot of times after each other.... I added the method `LoadTemplateList();` on the spot where you put the comment "process event here"! Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: "same result" - meaning the even handler is still executing multiple times?  If that's the case, unless you are able to post a [MCVE] we probably can't help you with the information we have.

Comment: The code that I added above should be enough to recreate the problem, because I can't share the database with you. If you got questions about the problem you can ask them, but I hoped that the information above was enough!

Comment: that's not what a [MCVE] is.  If you won't take the time to create that you shouldn't expect us to spend our time trying to debug your code for you.

Comment: What method? Decorate your handler with checks @Jason provided.

Comment: The app doesn't wait for LoadTemplateList() to finish, so it sets the handling to false, while it is true

Comment: That is because you didn't await the function.